# Accessing JS library functions from within processing.js script

Tags: javascript, function, external, processing.js

Im looking to access external functions from with a processing pjs script intergrated in the HTML5 canvas element.

Iv tried traditional methods of accessing the function however i seem unable to from within the datasrc script.

Can someone point me in the right direction??

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? What is the external javascript function? The pjs content? the container html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pjs script will have access to any globals, so you shouldn't have any trouble doing this.  We've written about this multiple times, for example:

http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/jsQuickStart#accessingjsobjectsfrompjs

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had access to the vairable however I was having trouble accessing functions as I'm attempting to write a custom library for my site. This also was very helpful.